# Is there anyway to speed up this batch update code using google script?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently attempting to update 1600-2000 rows of data in google sheets. I am parsing data from an API Fetch but it keeps timing out because the update is taking way too long. I don't really know how to post reusable code without giving out the API which I can't do. Does anyone know how I can speed up this process?

```
    function logDataInEveryCell3() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const vs = ss.getRange("A2:A1669").getValues().flat();
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let row = 2;
  vs.forEach(e => {
    let res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api” + e +token");
    let obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
    let items = obj["dispatches"]["items"];
    let vo = items.map(itm => [itm.vehicle.driver.contact.name])
    vo2 = vo.slice(-1);//good idea
    osh.getRange(row,3).setValues(vo2);
    row += vo2.length;
  });
```

}

Comment: Please removed the syntax errors in your code

Comment: res is undefined

Comment: Probably not UrlFetches can take a long time to complete,  If there is it might be by using the external api more efficiently rather than one at a time,

Comment: build the big array, then set all the values to one big range, rather than one at a time.  you shouldn't be setting ONE cell at a time in a for loop like that.

Comment: It might help a little by pushing vo2 into an array and they using seetValues at the end

Comment: That's not what the original code did.  That setValues is a 2D array going to a single cell.  That's just dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function logDataInEveryCell() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const vs = ss.getRange("A2:A51").getValues().flat();
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  osh.clearContents();
  let l = 1;
  let a = [];
  vs.forEach(e => {
    let res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("API" + e + "Token");
    let obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
    let items = obj["dispatches"]["items"];
    let vo = items.map(itm => [itm.vehicle.driver.contact.name])
    a.push(vo.slice(-1));
  });
  a.flat(1);
  osh.getRange(l,1,a.length,a[0].length).setValues(a);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

Comment: Attempting it now! Will let you know how it works. Thanks for all your help so far Cooper.